# Calculate the Integral for n=1,.....,n

Tags: integration

Calculate the Integral for all n=1,...n

$\int _{ 0 }^{ \pi/2 }{ \frac { \sin^n(x) }{ \sin^n(x)+ \cos^n(x) }  } dx$

hint: substituion with $x= (\pi/2)-t$

I tried it many times, but always ended up with the Integralsinus $Si(x)$ which i cant use.
Thanks for help

Comment: What do you get when you apply the given hint?

Comment: with the hint below i got it, i got stuck at the second substitution of cos(t)/(cos(t)+sin(t)

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-t$. Then

\begin{align}
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin^nx}{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}dx&=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^0\frac{\sin^n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)}{\sin^n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)+\cos^n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)}dt\\
&=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos^nt}{\cos^nt+\sin^nt}dt\\
&=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos^nx}{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}dx
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin^nx}{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}dx&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin^nx}{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos^nx}{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$I(n)=\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac{\pi}2 }{ \frac { \sin^n(x) }{ \sin^n(x)+\cos^n(x) }  } dx$$

Using the substitution $x\to\pi/2-x$, we find

$$I(n)= \int _{ 0 }^{ \frac{\pi}2 }{ \frac { \cos^ n(x) }{ \sin^n(x)+\cos^n(x) } }dx$$

What happens when you add these two forms of $I(n)$?